# Python: Can I make an auto-login script without having to open the browser?

Tags: authentication, bots

I'm fairly new to programming. I want to make a log-in automation for Facebook, but I want the auto-login process to be hidden(by having python do the automation without it opening up the browser).

Is it possible? If yes, what are the modules I have to setup to begin doing so.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not meant to implement entire solutions for you. It is supposed to help with specific programming problems. Please do some basic research, try to write some code and come back with specific problems.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was not asking for the entire solution, I only ask if it is possible, and if so, what is the module I need to start researching for the syntax.